# Activiti BPMN generation via GUI tools rather than manual bean definition/XML config

Tags: auto-generate, bpmn, activiti

we're looking for a GUI-based development tool for Activiti processes in order to reduce the formal development tasks associated with the XML configuration and Java support. Ideally we want to end up with any changes (config and functional) being GUI-driven so as to reduce the requisite skills for support. This leads me to believe we're after something like the functionality used in Oracle SOA Suite/Jdeveloper or Mule, whereby we can create the backend logic via the GUI and not have any re-development or code changes as such - the config will be done on a high-level via a designer using wizards or the like.

We have looked at the Activiti Eclipse plugin properties, and decomposing existing BPMN diagram files to their XML and modifying it manually, but this still requires generation of the service classes to support the process.
Does anybody have any experience with this type of requirement or any designer front-end for the process that uses wizards or dialogs for auto-generating the supporting backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating backend logic (this means Java) via GUI is not something activiti is intended for. You can create the diagram with several tools and this can be done for non-IT people. But you have to implement Service Tasks by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that was the conclusion we drew too.